# open an object JSON in Java ( servlet )

Tags: java, json, servlets

I decree in a separate folder of the json file type.
These files can not open them and eleborarli with javascript through the $ .getJson ().
But the same thing can do even in java, or rather, I can open a .json in java and process as the function $ .getJson in javascript?

my json is :

node1.json

```js
{
    "title": "Risoluzioni problemi 1",
    "id": "node1",
    "radioList": [{
            "text": "possibile problema 1",
            "value": "node2"
        },
        {
            "text": "possibile problema 2",
            "value": "node3"
        },
        {
            "text": "possibile problema 3",
            "value": "node4"
        }
    ]
}
```

to work with json, javascript / jquery I used:

```js
$.getJSON('node1.json', function (data){

            createNextNodes(data);
        });
```

Everything works. Now I would like to do the same thing with ajax requests to a server, the question I asked myself is, as in jquery can i open and edit the files node1.json in a servlet?

even better in Java (servlets) that a function / method that does the same thing for $ .getJson () jquery?

Comment: You need to make a request them and fetch them. Javascript cannot have access to file system.

Comment: did you try anything? if yes then show your efforts

Comment: He's in Java and asks for an equivalent to js' `$.getJson()`, if I deciphered his question correctly.

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] with an [edit] to your question? It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

in Java you can make as below

```
public void parseJson(String path) {
    JSONParser jsonp = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = jsonp.parse(new FileReader(path));
        JSONObject jsono = (JSONObject) obj;
        String title = (String) jsono.get("title");
        String id = (String) jsono.get("id");

        System.out.println(title);///or edit
        System.out.println(id);//or edit
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsono.get("radioList");
        Iterator<String> it = array.listIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object next = it.next();
            System.out.println(next);//or edit
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```